# Do I have to pick up all loot at the end of each wave?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

So, do I have to pick up all loot at the end of each wave or will items keep lying around until the level is completed? What happens with the items in case you fail the level? Do they get added to your inventory?

Comment: If I recall corrently they get converted to their gold value and added to your bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the loot left on the ground at the end of a wave will be converted to mana equal to it's sale value. Note that if you're playing with multiple people that total value of all the loot "sold" will be split between everybody. For example:

- 1 million mana with one person will go to that one person (obviously)
- 1 million mana with 4 people will give each person 250k mana

It's an unwritten rule of the DD community to leave everything except gear that's an improvement on your own at the end of a wave. Source: 600 hours of Dungeon Defenders played

Comment: That will make things easier.. it's quite tedious to have to pick everything up.

Comment: It really is lol. Be careful though, I've had situations where there is so much loot on the ground that things get added to the mana pool seconds after they drop.

Comment: @slow_excellence I believe they added a patch so that higher quality items are less likely to be converted when the map is full.